# Wrap text around a lettrine-like chapter number

Tags: wrap, lettrine, wrapfig

Bibles are often printed with chapter numbers formatted much like the dropped capitals produced by the `lettrine` package. So that package can be used to insert chapter numbers. This works well when the start of the chapter coincides with the start of a new paragraph.

But sometimes some of the chapter breaks occur within a paragraph, in which case the chapter number should still be printed, with the paragraph text wrapping around it. I lack a great solution for this. I made an attempt with `wrapfig`, but I had a number of problems. I'm still having the best luck with `lettrine`, but
I have to manually place my chapter command where the linebreak should be. (And I actually have to put in a `\linebreak` to force justification of the previous line, and then a `\vspace` to eliminate the unwanted extra line.

Is there a way I can place a `\mychapter{}` call at the start of the actual chapter ("From inside ...") and have the paragraph wrap around the chapter number?

Perhaps I should ask if there is any fundamental obstacle to what I want. It would require modifying the line *above* the insertion point in many cases. Is that possible, or has that ship sailed by the time Tex gets to the macro (if placed where I want it placed)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand\mychapter[1]{\lettrine[nindent=0pt,findent=1em]{#1}{}}

\begin{document}
\dots\ At this the men greatly feared the Lord, and they
offered a sacrifice to the Lord and made vows to him.

Now the Lord provided a huge fish to swallow Jonah, and Jonah was in%
\linebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}% force line above to justify
\mychapter{2}%
the belly of the fish three days and three nights.
% Chapter 2 actually starts here, would like to put \mychapter{} call here
From inside the
fish Jonah prayed to the Lord his God.  He said: \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want a chapter break in the middle of a paragraph?  Interesting!

Comment: Yeah, well Stephen Langton set the chapter numbers in the 13th century, and modern scholars don't always agree with his choices! (In this particular case, some medieval scholars also disagreed.)

Comment: See also lettrine package.

Answer (score 1):

Letterine uses `\hangindent`, which can only be used at the start of a paragraph.  The trick is to make `\par` act like `\linebreak`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand\mychapter[1]{\lettrine[nindent=0pt,findent=1em]{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\nopar}{\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}}

\begin{document}
\dots\ At this the men greatly feared the Lord, and they
offered a sacrifice to the Lord and made vows to him.

Now the Lord provided a huge fish to swallow Jonah, and Jonah was in\nopar
\mychapter{2}%
the belly of the fish three days and three nights.
% Chapter 2 actually starts here, would like to put \mychapter{} call here
From inside the
fish Jonah prayed to the Lord his God.  He said: \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found that the `\strut` in `\nopar` seems to be the cause of a little surplus vertical space.  Using `\null` instead seems to correct that.

Comment: The \strut was just habit, since I usually use \nopar in minipages.